# Converting RESTResponse.Content into JSON Value or JSON Array Delphi

Tags: json, rest, delphi, response

I am working with a REST-Application that is receiving an ID from a Server and I'm trying to translate the Response into a JSONValue (or best case a JSON Array), but everytime I try this:

```
JValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(FRESTConnection.RESTResponse.Content);
```

It gives me an empty JSONValue, despite the Content containing exactly what I need in correct JSON Syntax.

I've also tried typecasting the Response into a JSONArray, which didnt work either and gave me an Array with the amount of Response Pairs I got as a response, but all of them were empty.

```
FRESTConnection.Data := TJSONArray(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(FRESTConnection.RESTResponse.Content));
```

FRESTConnection.Data is a TJSONArray.

Comment: Did you check _RESTResponse.Status.Success_ before? Also _TRestResponse_ offers a property _JSONValue_ directly, which is filled when the request succeeded and actually contains JSON.

Comment: The only way `ParseJSONValue()` returns `nil` is if it can't parse the `Content`, so make sure the `Content` is not blank or malformed in some way. In Delphi 10.3 and later, `ParseJSONValue()` has an optional `RaiseExc` option that can be enabled to raise an `EJSONParseException` exception on failure, which has properties to describe why and where the parse actually failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
FRESTConnection.RESTResponse.JSONValue
```

If you prefer you can cast:

```
FRESTConnection.RESTResponse.JSONValue as TJSONObject
```

or

```
FRESTConnection.RESTResponse.JSONValue as TJSONArray
```